# Can you merge Outlook 2007 Profiles?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Apps Sync Created a new Outlook Profile](https://superuser.com/questions/108121/google-apps-sync-created-a-new-outlook-profile)

I never even knew what profiles were. But now I have 2 (thanks to installing Google's synchronization plugin) and have to pick one whenever I launch Outlook.

It's really annoying, the whole reason I use a desktop email client is to let me monitor all my email accounts from one place. Can I merge the two?

Comment: Are you using Outlook as a stand alone product or with Exchange?   Do you know what a PST file is?

Comment: No, but there are ways around this to do in manually.